# Connection socket.io incremented after stopping the server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a problem with socket.io from nodeJs.

I am trying to create a connection from a client to a server. Once the client is connected, the server sends a message to the client (ack).
Until then, everything works fine but when I disconnect the server and restart it, it sends me the message twice to the client.
If I repeat the manipulation a third time, three messages will appear.

I have captured the problem:

[image: Connection socket.io incremented after stopping the server]

**client.js**

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8050', {
'forceNew':true
}); 

socket.on('connect', onConnect);
function onConnect(){
        console.log('connect ' + socket.id);

        socket.emit('sendConnect','First connect'); 
        socket.on("ack", function(data) {
            console.log("ack reçu");
        });  

        socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) { 
          console.log(reason); 
        });
}
```

**server.js**

```
var io = require("socket.io");
var sockets = io.listen(8050);

sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
       socket.on('sendConnect', function (data) {
           console.log("message :" + data);
           socket.emit('ack');
           socket.on('disconnect', function() {
               console.log('Got disconnect!');
           });
       });
});
```

I looked if this bug was already arriving without finding an answer.
I must surely be doing something wrong!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onConnect` function adds new event listeners each time the socket connects. Move the event subscriptions out of `onConnect` like this:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:8050', {
  forceNew: true
});

socket.on('connect', onConnect);

socket.on('ack', function(data) {
  console.log('ack reçu');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
  console.log(reason);
});

function onConnect() {
  console.log('connect ' + socket.id);

  socket.emit('sendConnect', 'First connect');
}
```

Comment: I understand exactly my error !! Thank you very much =)